# Comparison of two different coloured dyes using UV-vis spectra

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy, dye, absorbance

I know that Both solutions are a shade of purple due to the lack of absorbances in the red and blue regions, however am I correct in thinking that the peak slightly to the right of the 2 in this spectrum (showing both spectra on one report) would be more blue in colour since it absorbs more at longer wavelengths?[image]

Comment: Since you apparently collected the absorption spectra, do you have pictures of the solutions?

Comment: @Aurora. One of the dye absorbs the yellow strongly and more selectively. It must appear purple. The other dye does not absorb the yellow so strongly, but it absorbs more strongly the red and the blue. The optical effect of absorbing more red + blue must be similar to just and only absorbing yellow.

Comment: Yes, however I very foolishly didn’t label the report properly and am now trying to rationalise which solution corresponds to which spectrum